# Combinatorics of a quiz consisting of 10 true and false questions

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

A quiz consists of 10 true and false questions, each question is answered with either true or false (no blank questions)

1. How many of the possible answer sequences begin and end with the answer True?
2. If a student guesses at all 10 questions, what is the probability that they guess the correct answer to at least 8 of 10 questions?

I did a few of these but these two stumped me. I am a bit slow at maths so any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. We have free choice on the remaining $8$ slots, so $2^8$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1:
You can think as the number of possible answer sequences as the number of possible answer sequences for the eight true/false questions in between.  There are two possible answers for each of the eight questions; thus, the number of possible answer sequences is $2^8$.

Part 2:
You can use the binomial distribution.  The probability mass function for the number of successes $k$ out of $n$ trials of a binary experiment (success or failure) in which the probability of success is $p$ is as follows:

$$f(k;n,p) = {n\choose k}p^k(1 - p)^{n - k} $$

You want to calculate the probability of $k = 8$ successes out of $n = 10$ trials where the probability of success is $p = 0.5$; you can compute this as follows:

$${10\choose8}(0.5)^{10} = 0.0439$$

So your probability is approximately 0.044.